# Load mongodb collection to memory with node.js and mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

My requirement is to load active("status":"Active") documents from a certain collection and maintain data-binding between the in-memory collection and the actual collection in the mongoDB.
Once i change the status of a document to be "status":"Done" i want to remove it from the node memory.

I hope i explained my self correctly and thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried? what errors you are getting? what your road blocks are?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, i have an app set up with node.js, mongoose and express. I already managed to get collections from the DB however, since i'm new to node and mongoose, i do not know if by default mongoose collections which are populated are maintaining data-binding with the DB when some of the documents are changed.

My question is not regarding a code example, rather understanding how in-memory load of collections and data-binding between mongoose and mongoDB works

Comment: There's no data-binding between in-memory copies of documents and the actual documents in the collection. You have to requery the collection to pick up any changes.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks for the explanation!